# Hibernate not ingoring @Transient field

Tags: java, hibernate, transient

I have an entity that derives from an interface that defines a getter method. I mark it with `@Transient`, but still hibernate requires me to

1. Define a setter method.
2. Does include the field in all queries, causing a crash.

Isn't that what `@Transient` is for?

```
public interface Archiveable { @Transient Boolean getArchived(); }


@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Post implements Archiveable {
    
    @Override
    @Transient
    public Boolean getArchived() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure i am using this very construct in other forms as well.

Answer (score -1):

The @Transient annotation can be applied only to the fields, not the method definitions.

Comment: This is simply wrong. I have a lot of `@Transient` on methods, because the codebase i inherited has all hibernate annotations on the getter methods.

Comment: Of course if you have the corresponding fields, it will be applied to them. Bit in this question, I can't see the field that relates to the getArchived method. So how this should works?

Comment: Okay that might be the reason after all. I did not get that from your answer though.